# Firebase Web Debug Token different each time for App Check

Tags: firebase, flutter-web, firebase-app-check

I can't make my app work in local host with App Check. Each time the generated debug token is different so I can't add it in the console. The only way I made it work is to add programmatically to index.html the custom debug token I generated like this:

```
self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = '186152BD-4BAA-blabla';
```

is there a way to do this only for development environment? I know we can get the environment from Flutter inside flutter from String.getFromEnrironment but I don't know how I would do this with plain javascript before the app loads?

I read that adding localhost to the recaptcha key is a security breach so I didn't want to go that route.